# Active record, results illustration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Can someone explain this?

```
Post.where(:p_date => ((Time.now - 7.days)..(Time.now))).count
-> 4507
Post.where(:p_date => ((Time.now - 7.days).beginning_of_day..(Time.now).end_of_day)).count
-> 4794
```

While **p_date** is only ***date type*** without time.

Thank you

Comment: What are your time zone settings?

Comment: If you do `Post.where(pdate: Date.today - 7.days).count` does that equal the difference?

Comment: Time zone is GMT+3

Comment: @SteveTurczyn yes it will give the first results in the selected range

Comment: Post.where(:p_date => ((Date.today - 7.days).beginning_of_day..(Date.today).end_of_day)).count

Comment: @JohnFeltz, I think the time zone may be the cause this issue,  query detail from active record, first one "SELECT COUNT() FROM "posts" WHERE ("posts"."p_date" BETWEEN '2016-09-08 15:33:24.390596' AND '2016-09-15 15:33:24.390711') and the second one SELECT COUNT() FROM "posts" WHERE ("posts"."p_date" BETWEEN '2016-09-07 21:00:00.000000' AND '2016-09-15 20:59:59.999999')", it looks like the second one added additional day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `p_date` is a date column, pass dates into your query

```
Post.where(p_date: (7.day.ago.to_date .. Date.today)).count
```

which uses this query

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `posts` WHERE (`posts`.`p_date` BETWEEN '2016-09-08' AND '2016-09-15')
```

If you pass in time objects, the database will automatically compare against 0:00:00 time (at least on mysql and postgres) which is where you get your discrepancy from.

Comment: I am using Postgres and this is the query detail from active record, first one SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE ("posts"."p_date" BETWEEN '2016-09-08 15:33:24.390596' AND '2016-09-15 15:33:24.390711')
 and the second one 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE ("posts"."p_date" BETWEEN '2016-09-07 21:00:00.000000' AND '2016-09-15 20:59:59.999999')

Comment: it seems that there is one day added to second query

Comment: Right, so postgres will also cast the date object to a datetime with a timestamp of 00:00:00 and since your two queries involve two different time ranges you'll get different answers.

Since the column is a date, if you use dates as your range you'll get consistent and correct answers.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is a good solution. but the main reason because the time zone

Comment: The main reason is because you are literally using two different times in your queries (Time.now vs beginning of the day).  You would still run into varying results regardless of the timezone settings.  And the only reason the times matter in the first place is because you're making the database cast the column into a time.